# Evaluate Swift expressions in LLDB

Tags: swift, lldb

I want to define a Swift extension, including a method / computed var, only for LLDB debugging purposes. Here is the regular Swift code:

```
extension Collection where Self.Element == Int {
  var elementsOver30: [Self.Element]? {
    return self.filter { $0 > 30 }
  }
}
```

How can I define `elementsOver30` in this example in pure LLDB? I think `expression` command is the right tool to use, but I sometimes get parsing errors.

Also, is there an equivalent syntax for other Swift symbols in LLDB, like `struct`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Working with Swift code in LLDB

Most Swift code can be executed as part of LLDB if it's part of the stdlib with the right syntax. The key is to prefix *type* names with the symbol identifier `$`. I've used `$` even for variable names here (new LLDB improvements make this unnecessary) because I prefer to distinguish LLDB definitions.

### Extensions

With improvements to LLDB, you can actually copy-paste the Swift code directly after expression.

I've added an example for your extension with `$` symbols for clarity:

```
(lldb) expression
extension Collection where Self.Element == Int {
var $elementsOver30: [Self.Element]? {
return self.filter { $0 > 30 }
}
}
(lldb) po [32,31,4].$elementsOver30
▿ Optional<Array<Int>>
  ▿ some : 2 elements
    - 0 : 32
    - 1 : 31
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after `expression` prompts a multi-line evaluation where we can input the remaining Swift code.

### Structs/Class definitions

```
(lldb) expression
struct $Person {
let name: String
}
(lldb) po let $pranav = $Person.init(name: "pranav")
(lldb) po $pranav
▿ $Person
  - name : "pranav"
```

### Reading a Swift instance from memory

Sometimes, we need to read Swift code using Objective-C in LLDB. For example, if we have a Swift file with a View Controller:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
...
}
```

We can print the dynamic type of the result of a memory address as follows:

```
(lldb) expr -O --language objc -- 0x14160c260
<SharedSettings.LoginViewController: 0x14160c260>
```

### View Swift docs

Use `type lookup` to read a minified version of the type definitions:

```
(lldb) type lookup Equatable
protocol Equatable {
  static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Swift.Bool
}
extension Swift.Equatable {
  static func != (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Swift.Bool
}
```